# ParseExeption with Date?

Tags: java, date, parsing, exception

I got an exception while parsing date format?

**java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10-10-2016"**

at this line:

**newSelection5 = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse((String)CalDcB.getSelectedItem());**

The date is set as: 
**CalDcB = new DateComboBox(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));**

I tried also without Locale.English.

There was also a danger Alert "null".

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it works without an exception.

I used:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
newSelection5 = df.parse((String)CalDcB.getSelectedItem());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could construct a [`SimpleDateFomat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that matches your format and use that.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = df.parse("10-10-2016");
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "30-10-2016" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) 
)
```

## `LocalDate`

FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes now legacy. Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "30-10-2016" , f );
```

> ld.toString(): 2016-10-30

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("10-10-2016");
```

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answer?